# C Order of Operations Contradiction between Eclipse, CLion, Code::Blocks and more

Tags: c, eclipse, codeblocks, clion, operator-precedence

I have seemingly very basic question about the order of operations in c, specifically involving the increment operator.

If I have this code:

```
int x,y;
y = 4;
x = ++y + y--;

printf("x: %d y: %d", x,y)
```

The output I expect is:
`x: 10 y: 4`

I got this using the process described here:
http://ntci.on.ca/compsci/java/ch2/2_3.html
(See Example 2, in the red box)

When I run this in eclipse on Mac with the MacOSX GCC, this is the answer it gives.  Great.

However, when I use CLion (under MinGW), it gives:
`x: 9 y: 4`

So does Code::Blocks (with MinGW), and many online compilers such as:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler
and
jdoodle's
and
tutorialspoint's.

What gives?  Is eclipse and my understanding of the order of operations in C wrong?

Or are CLion, Code::Blocks, and a ton of online compilers wrong?

Comment: The compilers are fine. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: Why would you want to increment and decrement a value in the same expression anyway?

Comment: @WeatherVane I can think of some funny applications when it's some hardware register...

Comment: In this case, different compilers are free to translate the same thing differently, because the C standard does not define the order in which the operands are evaluated.  In other words, never do this, at best it's a bug waiting to happen.  A new compiler release, different optimization setting, etc. could suddenly cause the behavior to change.

Comment: All of the examples I have found involve assigning a variable to itself, with the increment operator.  Like `i = i++ + --i`.  It's good to know that this applies in general!

Comment: The description page you cited is about Java.  Java has well-defined rules for expressions like this, but C does not.  In C, this expression is *undefined*, specifically because it tries to modify variable `y` twice.